# Complex registration forms examples for test cases creation practicing

Tags: manual-testing, training, testcase

Could you please suggest some non-trivial web forms for test case preparation training? The form should concern different field validation warnings, number autocomplete, dynamic fields, etc. Nice sample: [Google SignUp form](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The following site offers many sample forms and will allow you to practice your test cases easily.

http://www.wufoo.com/examples/

Answer (score 2):

Svetlana, since most publicly-available registration forms for large websites fit your criteria, I'd imagine you could use any of them.

You might also consider some Shopping-Carts.

Many file upload/download forms (such as those for photos, etc) meet your criteria.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Usually social networks / web mail services have a nice many-different-fields reg forms, e.g.:

1. http://mail.yandex.ru/
2. http://e.mail.ru/cgi-bin/signup?from=main
3. BTW, SO profile page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953175/peter-l is a nicest thing to train your cases creation skills, since there are many "hidden" parts, tabs and features which may be quite easily missed by not experienced QA.

Good luck with your learning!

Answer (score 1):

Also add to the list:

- **Financial institutions** - Banks and Credit Cards.  They also provide an option to select second layer of authentication during registration